# Дрібні заощадження (переважно дитячі) краще зберігати в скарбничці, копійничці чи деінде?

Tags: вибір-слова, синоніми, іменники

Приватбанк пропонує послугу для накопичення коштів "**[Скарбничка](https://privatbank.ua/kopi)**", символом якої обрав керамічне поросятко, як за методичкою - за першою асоціацією ще з дитинства.

Однак, СУМ відмічає, що це слово застаріле, та й не дуже схоже, що для збирання саме монет.

> **[СКАРБНИ́ЧКА](http://sum.in.ua/s/skarbnychka)**, и, жін., заст. Скринька, шкатулка для зберігання коштовностей, грошей і т. ін. — Да пак ще ж і сережки треба
>   перемінити, — згадала пані й подала доньці скарбничку (Любов Яновська,
>   I, 1959, 117).
>
> Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 9, 1978. — Стор. 253.

Ресурс **[Словопедія](http://lang.slovopedia.org.ua/11/53402/140890.html)**, пропонує **`скарбничка`**, **`скарбонька`**, **`карнавка`**.

СУМ щодо цих двох додаткових варіантів позначає, що церковні або застарілі. Та я й не зустрічала, щоб їх використовували в запитуваному значенні.

> [**СКАРБО́НА**](http://sum.in.ua/s/skarbona), и, жін.
>
> 1. церк. Скринька, в яку віруючі кидають гроші на потреби церкви. Два злодії в опівночі Костьол обкрадають; Обшарили всі скарбони, Святих
>      обдирають (Степан Руданський, Тв., 1956, 135); [Юда:] Я ж ні шага не
>      мав. Се правда, я глядів у них скарбони, — бо я вважався більш «від
>      сього світа», ніж тії чисті душі (Леся Українка, III, 1952, 138);  // 
>      заст. Скринька, шкатулка для зберігання коштовностей, грошей і т. ін.
> 2. перен., рідко. Те саме, що скарб 3. — Руки, Докійко, руки — то все наше багатство, то наше добро, то наша скарбона! (Ольга Кобилянська,
>      II, 1956, 24).
>
> Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 9, 1978. — Стор. 254.
>
> [**КАРНА́ВКА**](http://sum.in.ua/s/karnavka), и, жін. Металева закрита коробка з отвором у
>   кришці для збирання грошей (переважно в церкві); скарбничка, скарбона.
>   Того ж таки дня піп виймав гроші з карнавки (Михайло Коцюбинський, I,
>   1955, 95); Суворий чернець стояв поряд, виразно показуючи перстом на
>   карнавку, куди треба було кидати пожертви (Олесь Донченко, III, 1956,
>   144).
>
> Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 4, 1973. — Стор. 108.

Якось в одному з інтернет-магазинів дитячих іграшок трапився варіант **`копійничка`**. Як на мене, досить прийнятний. [Google пошук](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0&ei=jEFTXLPOC-2CmgXwsZTQAQ&start=0&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwizxLWX1pjgAhVtgaYKHfAYBRo4FBDy0wMIbA&biw=1920&bih=920) видає певну кількість результатів (222). Але поки що не зустрічала в словниках.

**Який з варіантів найбільш відповідає шуканому тлумаченню? Може, якийсь із не згаданих у запитанні?**

Answer (score 1):

Дивно, що СУМ пише, що слово "скарбничка" застаріле. Можемо зустріти його сучасне визначення на сторінці [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0):

> **Скарбни́чка** — спеціальне пристосування для накопичення монет. Представляє з себе ємність (у вигляді коробочки, фігурки тварини тощо)
>   з вузькою щілиною, в яку опускаються монети. В залежності від
>   наявності отвору для виїмки грошей копилки можуть бути одноразового і
>   багаторазового використання. Одна з найпопулярніших форм скарбнички —
>   свиня.

Також спробував подивитися, які є переклади російського слова "копилка". Звернувся до онлайн словника [Глосб](https://uk.glosbe.com/ru/uk/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0), бо там зразу є приклади. Серед найпопулярніших варіантів знову було слово "**скарбничка**", а також такі слова як "**банка**" та "**скриня**" (ну, очевидно, тут просто називається предмет, де зберігаються гроші).

Також варіант перекладу "**скарбничка**" дають сайти [HowToSay](http://ru.howtosay.org/ru_uk/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0) і [GufoMe](https://gufo.me/dict/ruuk/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0):

> ¤ детская копилка -- дитяча скарбничка

На форумі ЖЖ також обговорювали це питання. І серед запропонованих варіантів перекладу "копилка" були все ті ж "скарбничка", "[скарбонка](http://sum.in.ua/s/skarbonka)", "[скарбона](http://sum.in.ua/s/skarbona)" і "карнавка". Хоча останній варіант справді швидше буде мати значення: Металева закрита коробка з отвором у кришці для збирання грошей (переважно в церкві)".

Мені відомо, що є ще слво "[шкатулка](http://sum.in.ua/s/shkatulka)", але це радше для зберігання цінних маленьких речей, а не грошей. А якщо пошукаємо [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/skarbnycja), то знайдемо ще варіант "**скарбниця**" (немає жодних позначок біля значення):

> Скринька, шкатулка для зберігання коштовностей, грошей і т. ін.

Можливо, в СУМ-20 слово "скарбничка" вже буде мати своє сучасне значення.

Comment: Я й звіряю завжди спершу із СУМ-20, але коли слово відсутнє, переадресовує на попередню редакцію. А от цікаво тоді щодо "копійнички", звідки з'явилось, бо вже знаходжу приклади [вживання](https://opinionua.com/2019/01/22/sezon-devyanosto-devyatogo-abo-komanda-mri%D1%97-valeriya-lobanovskogo/) не тільки на комерційних ресурсах. Та це вже окреслюється окреме запитання.